# is there any way to get city name for Google Place picker android

Tags: android, google-geocoder, gmsplacepicker

I am trying to get city name from Google place picker. is there any way that we can get city name using place picker API. i know we can not simply get it from API by placing `place.getCity();` Below is my code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER){

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);

                final CharSequence name = place.getName();
                final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
                final CharSequence phone = place.getPhoneNumber();
                final String placeId = place.getId();
                final LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

                if(place.getLocale() != null) {
                    String aname = place.getLocale().toString();
                    areaname.setText(aname);
                }

                location.setText(address);
                gname.setText(name);
                latlon.setText(String.valueOf(latLng));

            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want any null values in city. i read `Geocoder` will give mostly null values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using geocoder

```
final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this,data);
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
try
{
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude, 1);
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
    //String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);  

} catch (IOException e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also you can try to call webservice and parse json result to get city.
Just pass the lat/ lng you get from placepicker in below url.
In the result administrative_area_level_2 represents the city

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23,72&sensor=true

Comment: error change address type to java.util.List<android.location.Address>

Comment: import java.util.List;

Comment: For address >import android.location.Address;

Comment: ok i did changed. but when i try to set it  in Text view is giving very odd values

Comment: Please print log

Comment: thank you for you help Nancy. i just added city.setText(String.valueOf(addresses.get(0).getLocality()));

Comment: Be careful with Address.getAddressLine(). Don't assume the number of lines. Use Address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() to check.